# How to show two core data entity in one table view

Tags: ios, swift, entity-framework, uitableview, core-data

I have stored one name and one number(Double) in two entitys so I have got two names and two numbers so I want to show both entitys in one table view. I reach it to show one entity in the table view with this code:

```
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NormalTimerTableCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! NormalTimerTableCell

    let timerName = TimerTitle[indexPath.row]
    let timerZeit = TimerZeit[indexPath.row]
    let NormalTimerName = timerName.value(forKey: "normaltimername") as! String
    let NormalTimerZeit = timerZeit.value(forKey: "normaltimerzeit") as! Double

    cell.NormalTimerNameLbl?.text = "\(NormalTimerName)"
    cell.NormalTimerZeitLbl?.text = "\(NormalTimerZeit)"
    return cell
```

But now I have got one more entity with one name and one number but I don´t know how to make it. I hope i could describe it so you understand it and i hope you could help me.

Comment: So, you want to display 2 cells in your tableview ?

Comment: Yes, I want wo make two cells and one cell is connect to one entity.

Comment: Apple doc for coredata https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html?utm_source=iosstash.io

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Fetching the data of the two entities from Core Data or showing the already fetched data in a tableView? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41081858/edit) your question accordingly.